# Swift using UNUserNotificationCenter when app is running

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm creating an alarm using UNUserNotificationCenter.App Works well when the app is in the background or exits
However, there is no alarm if the app is running.

I heard that there is no alarm if the app is running. Is it true?

If not, how can I get an alarm when the app is running?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your local notification not triggered when the app is running. If the app is in running state, local notification triggered `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. So manage user notification in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' also. I hope this will work. Or let me know more about your code.